# Role based Auhtorization is not working as expected in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I have followed the NestJs documentation and added the following rolebased auth guards which is not working.

I always get headers undefined or context.switchToHttp().getRequest() is undefined.

I am using graphql with nestjs.

My Resolver:

```
@Resolver(() => User)
export class UsersResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles(ROLES.ADMIN)
  @Query(() => [User], { name: 'users' })
  findAll(): Promise<UserDto[]> {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
}
```

UsersModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role]), AuthModule],
  providers: [UsersResolver, UsersService, AuthResolver],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Roles Guard :

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    Logger.log('RolesGuard Called');
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<string[]>('roles', [context.getHandler(), context.getClass()]);

    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    return requiredRoles.some(role => user.roles?.includes(role));
  }
}
```

Auth Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    PassportModule.register({
      defaultStrategy: 'jwt',
    }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'THIS_IS_A_SECRET',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthenticationService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Getting this error :
[image]

I have added in RolesGuard in the app.module.

{ provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: RolesGuard }

Comment: Where do you bind the `RolesGuard` in your server?

Comment: I have added in RolesGuard in the app.module.{ provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: RolesGuard } @JayMcDoniel